# фильтр в magento

Tags: cms, magento, filter

Есть ли в стандартных темах Magento фильтр(бренды,характеристик,цвет) в сайдбаре?если да, то как его отобразить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, нужно установить атрибут категории is anchor в значение yes. Потом заполнить атрибуты товара. Причем атрибуты, по которым должна производиться фильтрация должны быть глобальными, иметь тип ввода "select" или "multiselect"и в поле used for layered navigation должно стоять "Filterable(with results)"